# Nullpointer exception in anylogic when using checkbox in parameters variation

Tags: simulation, anylogic

I'm doing a school project where I have to make a simulation of a restaurant. I'm using anylogic ver 8.7.6.
I have a resource pool in Main, and I want to have a checkbox in parameters variation that would change the capacity of the resource pool in Main. The code in parameters variaton in the before simulation run section is

`if (checkZamestnankyna.isSelected()){ root.pracovnicky.set_capacity(1); }`

(checkZamestnankyna is the checkbox and pracovnicky is the resource pool). The problem is that I collect some statistics (one of them is for instance this one: `statsAvgDlzkaRadu.add(root.statsDlzkaRadu.mean());` ) in the after simultion run section and I'm getting a nullpointer exception. All works just fine when the checkbox is not checked. I don't really see how those two things are related or why am I getting the exception.

Thanks.

Comment: Probably and instantiation problem of the RP. Do not change the capacity directly. Change a new parameter on main `myCapacity` and set the resource pool capacity to use that.

Comment: Please add the error message, it probably contains more information about where the NPE occurred